# How to replace/delete specific lines in subtitles (text) file?

Tags: batch-file, replace, find, subtitle, remove-if

So far, I've created a batch file which adds suffix to the files' names from the selected folder, which types are:

1. *.avi
2. *.mkv
3. *.mp4
4. *.ass

Now, I would like to add the option to search for specific text through the `*.srt` / `*.ass` files (subtitles files) and to delete the lines which contains the found text (if it does exist in the files). I would also like to have the option to replace the found text with another.

I hope what I have requested is possible and really appreciate any help you can provide.

**My code so far:**

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Select the folder via WSH Shell.Application BrowseForFolder method
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"') do set "folder=%%a"
if not defined folder goto :EOF
cd "%folder%"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D *.avi *.mkv *.mp4 *.ass ^| findstr /I /V ".created_by_me"') do (
   set "fileName=%%a"

   rem Convert the file name to lowercase letters
   for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
      set "fileName=!fileName:%%a=%%a!"
   )

   if "!fileName!" equ "%%a" (
      rem The original file name have all lowercase letters
      ren "%%a" "%%~Na.created_by_me%%~Xa"
   ) else (
      rem The original file name include at least one uppercase letter
      ren "%%a" "%%~Na.Created_By_Me%%~Xa"
   )

)
goto :EOF


@end


// JScript section

var shl = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var folder = shl.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder.\nThis extension will add a \".HebSubs-Tvil.Me\" suffix to each file of the following types: *.ASS; *.AVI; *.MKV; *.MP4", 0, 0x00);
WSH.echo(folder ? folder.self.path : "");
```

Comment: you can't use the same variable (`%%a`) in both `for` loops, because they are nested.

Comment: @Stephan - Not true. It is not a good practice, as the code can be hard to interpret. But nested FOR loops *can* reuse variables defined by the parent - it works just fine.

Comment: So you want to delete or replace certain text within your files? your actual code only manipulates file names but not the contents...

Comment: @aschipfl True. At the moment it only works on the files' names as I wrote. I'm not sure how to find and edit the inside

Comment: To delete lines containing a certain string, use `find /V` or `findstr /V` (add `/I` to search case-insensitively); to replace such lines, use `for /F` to read the file line per line and check each one for the search string...